# GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am learning and programming a game for android using libgdx and i have got stuck on this error for quite a long period of time. I have enclosed the following content

1. The code.
2. The command i used to access the asset.
3. Screenshot that contains the error when i debug the code on android.
4. Screenshot of my Package Explorer.
5. All the possible combinations i tried to get the code working.

1.The Code

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;  
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetErrorListener;  
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager;  
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;  
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;    
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;  
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Disposable;

public class Gameassetloader implements Disposable, AssetErrorListener {

public static final String TAG = Gameassetloader.class.getName();
public static Gameassetloader instance = new Gameassetloader();
private AssetManager assetManager;

/** Load the appropriate texture for the respective entities **/
public AssetCharacter boy;
public AssetRock rock;
public AssetShield shield;

/** singleton: prevent instantiation from other classes **/

private Gameassetloader(){}
public void init(AssetManager assetManager)
 {
    this.assetManager = assetManager;

    //set asset manager error handler
    assetManager.setErrorListener(this);

    //load texture atlas
    assetManager.load(Gameconstants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_OBJECTS,TextureAtlas.class);

    //start loading assets and wait until finished
    assetManager.finishLoading();

    Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "# of assets loaded:" + assetManager.getAssetNames().size);

    for (String a : assetManager.getAssetNames())
        Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "asset:" + a);

    TextureAtlas atlas = assetManager.get(Gameconstants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_OBJECTS);

    //enable texture filtering for pixel smoothing
    for(Texture t : atlas.getTextures())
        t.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear,TextureFilter.Linear);

    //create game resource objects

    boy = new AssetCharacter(atlas);
    rock = new AssetRock(atlas);
    shield = new AssetShield(atlas);
}

public void dispose() { assetManager.dispose(); }


 @Override
 public void error(String fileName, Class type, Throwable throwable) 
  {
    Gdx.app.error(TAG, "Couldn't load asset' " + fileName + "'", (Exception)throwable); 
  }

}
```

2.The Command

```
 public static final String TEXTURE_ATLAS_OBJECTS ="gdxgame-android/assets/packed/packed.png";
```

3.Screenshot of Package Explorer
http://i1294.photobucket.com/albums/b608/Abhishek_M369/PackageExplorer_zpsd2589ee2.jpg

4.Screenshot of Error log (Android DDMS)
http://i1294.photobucket.com/albums/b608/Abhishek_M369/ErrorLog_zps8a4a68d9.jpg

5.All the possible combinations i tried

```
 "/gdxgame-android/assets/packed/packed.png";
 "gdxgame-android/assets/packed/packed.png";
 "/assets/packed/packed.png";
 "assets/packed/packed.png";
 "/packed/packed.png";
 "packed/packed.png";
 "/packed.png";
 "packed.png";

 public static FileHandle location = Gdx.files.internal("assets/packed.png");
 public static final TEXTURE_ATLAS_OBJECT = location.toString();

 //this caused shutdown of emulator
 public static FileHandle location = Gdx.files.internal("assets/packed.png");
 public static final TEXTURE_ATLAS_OBJECT = location.readString();

 // I even tried setting the build path of the asset folder as source folder
 // Also tried placing the image in the data folder.
 // Tried using the absolute path too , i.e Gdx.files.absolute("the absolute");
 // Tried passing the absolute path directly as string
```

Nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: Just a guess try using `Gdx.files.classpath("assets/packed.png");`.

Comment: Not working mate :(, still getting error reading file

Comment: I think your locations specified for `Gdx.files.internal` are all wrong, including the fjle handles and the texture_atlas_objects constant, check https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets to align it to their \assets\data\... setup

Comment: does it matter. Placing the assets even under data and then using it via command gdx.files.internal("data/***.png") still yields me error and yeah i keep refreshing the folders since i am using eclipse. 

and i am passing a string with path whether i use another variable or pass it directly, i don't think it should matter as even the first argument that's required for the method load() is also a string.

Comment: i will still give it a try and also try to use other random images just to ensure there is nothing wrong with the image file.

Comment: Nope not working, i am loading it directly and this time its the default image from libgdx and this is the command i used

assetManager.load("data/libgdx.png",Texture.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was very simple, the problem lied in the different versions of libgdx and the documentation. The answer explained below will solely confirm to libgdx version 0.9.8 only.

(Note: The usage of Texturepacker GUI was used to pack textures && not the method from the libgdx library)

First the "assetManager" had to be supplied with a file that contains the **coordinates of the images** which was a **mistake** here as i was supplying the packed image.

The GL20 should be able to parse **NPOT** images but it was unable to do so and the reason remains unknown so i had to pack the texture to a **POT** which was accomplished by selecting the POT options in the GUI. After doing this i was able to load the newly POT image easily with the following code

```
/**Mention only the folder/file under the asset dir**/

public class Gameconstants { public static final String location = "packed/packed.txt" }

/**access the same using the following command**/

private AssetManager assetManager;
assetManager.load(Gameconstants.location,Texture.class);
```

This Answer may not be very convincing but it surely solved my problem.

Thank you to all who helped :)